# Excel - Formula for changing value to another cell

Tags: excel

I want a formula to make ever 7.5 in a cell equal 1 in another.

e.g:

```
7.5 Hours = 1 Day(s) 
15 Hours = 2 Day(s)
```

Comment: then write formula to do that or do basic excel tutorial

Comment: This is excel basics. Maybe first read an online excel tutorial.

Comment: 7.5/7.5 = 1, 15/7.5 = 2, 22.5/7.5 = 3… Have you tried googling it? This is one of the most basic formulas possible.

Comment: The 7.5 is the sum of another table and should grow over time.. so if 8 Hours = 1 Day... I suppose could make it say 1/2 day once increased to the correct figure. I don't want to make another table for that... just make it up every 1/2 a Day when it hits a mile stone.    Also If this was on Google I wouldn't be asking on here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if A1 contains 7.5 then write in B1 `=A1/7.5`.

Comment: Thank you. All I wanted, Been ages since I used Excel.

Answer (score 0):

You could, of course, go way over the top for this simple task and use vlookup as shown - very handy for other situations though...
[image]